# Unnamed return variable

Tags: tokens

I'm facing a compilation error while writing a smart contract of sending tokens to other contracts.

```
Warning: Unnamed return variable can remain unassigned. Add an explicit return with value to all non-reverting code paths or name the variable.
   --> .deps/npm/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol:200:32:
    |
200 |     ) internal view  returns  (bytes memory) {
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, this is a warning regarding the return value. It's suggesting you name the return value. This will not affect the code logic in any way but it's better to consider naming the return values.